# Are there antibiotics for all bacteria somewhere in the earth?

Tags: bacteriology, antibiotics, biomedical-engineering

When I read about Penicillin, I found that it came from a green mold to protect itself.

If all bacteria and/or molds in competition to survive,
can we believe that there is an antibiotic for each bacterium somewhere in the earth?

In other words, just like bad bacteria change themselves to resist against the existing antibiotics, could good bacteria/molds produce antibiotics against the bad bacteria?

If so, can we use them like Penicillin, or should we still develop most of them?

Comment: Life is a constant arms race between organisms and their pathogens, each pushing the other to adapt ways to survive. Humans with competent immune systems are able to make their own bactericides, the only issue is the time it takes to mount this response, days to weeks, versus the replicative power of the bacteria and the virulence of their exotoxins. Vaccines against the most potent of toxins provide steady levels of antibodies to neutralize proteins that make snake venoms seem wimpy. Many antibiotics just keep bacterial populations in check until the host immune system can respond.

Comment: One other point is that you would have to do extensive testing to see what the toxicity of a bactericidal compound is on mammals. Penicillin goes after bacterial ability to produce a Lipopolysaccharide cell wall, something we don't have. Others take advantage of blocking ribosomal subunits that are different than ours, so we can use them without blocking our own ability to produce proteins. If the compounds we discover have specificity for a receptor that we make as well, then we can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of antibiotics that remain undiscovered is huge, but is estimated to be tens of thousands of compounds.

The number of bacteria that remain undiscovered is also huge, but is estimated to be perhaps millions of species.

Resistance to antibiotics is developed by bacteria in response to other bacteria and human antibiotic use, but in theory all antibiotics should work on previously unexposed bacteria. In practice there are resistance mechanisms that operate on whole classes of antibiotics at once([drug exporters](http://jac.oxfordjournals.org/content/56/1/20.full), for instance). So there might be a bacterium that happens to be actively or passively resistant to every antibiotic on the planet, but it's a question of statistics. I think it's pretty unlikely but there are a lot of bacteria, so it's theoretically possible. (It wouldn't be a dangerous pathogen, that amount of drug-resistance genes would 'weigh down' the genome and make it slow to divide, and all those transporters would be great immune system targets. The human immune system would eat it for breakfast.)

What is true is for every bacteria, there are at least some antibiotics it's already resistant to. Furthermore, some antibiotics aren't useful because they aren't selective enough and they are simply poisons. (We use them for chemotherapy agents sometimes, but they're not useful antibiotics).

Some fun examples: Vancomycin-resistant S. aureus is completely immune to nearly every antibiotic, including the last line of defense(methicillin) and the toxic really really last line of defense (vancomycin). It's susceptible to trimethoprim-sulfamethoxazole, one of the oldest antibiotics out there(~80 years old). On the other hand, the organism that causes tularemia is naturally immune to trimethoprim-sulfamethoxazole and always has been. It, in turn, is susceptible to nearly all other antibiotics.